# Adding state to bean generated via CGLIB's BeanGenerator

Tags: cglib

I see the following example code on how a Java Bean can be created dynamically. What I am not able to figure out is how I can update the state of an instance once created.
So in the following example how can I set the value of foo to "footest" for instance bean?

BeanGenerator bg = new BeanGenerator();

bg.addProperty("foo", Double.TYPE);

bg.addProperty("bar", String.class);

Object bean = bg.create();

Thanks
Kumar

Answer (score 2):

A few ways come to mind:

1/ Call "setFoo()" on "bean" using reflection.  Not pretty.

2/ Use a helper library to do the same thing - e.g. Commons-Beanutils o.a.c.BeanUtils.PropertyUtils.setProperty(bean, "foo", "footest").

This way works nicely for me.  You could use the Spring equivalent if you're already using Spring.

3/ Use CGLIB's BeanMap upon your new bean.  e.g.

Map beanMap = BeanMap.create(bean);
beanMap.put("foo", "footest");